# How to get the previous item on DropDownList before OnSelectedIndexChanged fires the event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How would I get the previous item on `DropDownList` before `OnSelectedIndexChanged` fires the event?

Example: I had a `DropDownList` that has names as its items ("John", "Mark"). By default the `SelectedIndex` is "John". Upon changing its index and selecting "Mark" the event `OnSelectedIndexChanged` will be triggered. When I use `ddlName.SelectedIndex` it will return only the index for "Mark" which I want to get is the index of "John".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't capture an event prior to the change, but you could easily store the previous value in a variable. Each time SelectedIndexChanged is fired, use the previous value and then set it to the new index (for the next time the event fires). To handle the case when it's a new selection (from the default), you can either set the variable when the page loads, or allow it to be null and have that alert you to the fact it's a new selection (which you can then handle however you like).

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="John" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mark" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Jim" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

.cs file code here:

```
public static int PreviousIndex;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlName.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlName.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other", "4"));
                PreviousIndex = ddlName.SelectedIndex;
            }

        }

        protected void ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string GetPreviousValue = ddlName.Items[PreviousIndex].Text;
            Response.Write("This is Previously Selected Value"+ GetPreviousValue);
            //Do selected change event here.

            PreviousIndex = ddlName.SelectedIndex;

        }
```

Comment: This won't work because the static variable will apply at the page level, not the user session level. Everyone using the site will have the `PreviousIndex`. The value would need to be stored in the ViewState.

Comment: not quite. The reason this won't work is because the PreviousIndex variable only exists during the postback.  Once the page is done rendering, it vanishes. Store the value in session, viewstate or a hidden field on the page, set it in Page_PreRender and it'll be ready for you on submit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `e.OldValues` property.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="esDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceddlEnrolmentStatus" DataTextField="EnrolmentStatusDescription" DataValueField="EnrolmentStatusID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StudentEnrolmentStatus") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceddlEnrolmentStatus" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCNTV1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [EnrolmentStatusID], [EnrolmentStatusDescription] FROM [tblEnrolmentStatuses] ORDER BY [EnrolmentStatusID]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And in code behind (assuming your dropdownlist is in a formview) ...

```
    protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
..
            String msg = "This is the new value " + e.NewValues["StudentEnrolmentStatus"].ToString()+ " and this is the old value " + e.OldValues["StudentEnrolmentStatus"].ToString();
..
    }
```