# How to get current value of a combobox before selectedindexchange method?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

Suppose I have a `ComboBox` and I want to get a previous value of the `ComboBox` just before it changes to the new selected index.

In a `TextBox` for example I can get it by using `KeyDown` of keyevents to get previous value but cant figure out what to do in a `ComboBox`.

I tried using dropdown event but it went on to call my `SelectedIndexChange` method of the `ComboBox` as and when dropdown event was being was called , which I don't want.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801831/how-to-get-the-previous-item-on-dropdownlist-before-onselectedindexchanged-fires

Comment: Possible duplicate:  or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496860/getting-previous-value-of-the-combobox

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmbBox1.Tag = cmbBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

private void cmbBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblPrevState.Text = cmbBox1.Tag.ToString(); // Just store the value of to a variable or do whatever you need to do with it here - each time it calls tag will contain previous index value
    cmbBox1.Tag = cmbBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

All you need to do is set SelectedIndexChangedevent on cmbBox1.

Comment: hey i dont understand how will I use it for combobox ...can u pls sugges ?

Comment: sorry missread combobox as checkbox, will change example to combobox now

Comment: See the thing is I have multiple tabs in a dialog box which contains the combobox....so how should I find the value for each tab?